# Performance problems using big points shapefile in TileMill

Tags: shapefile, tilemill

I've downloaded all the addresses in Italy from OSM and now I've a shapefile with more 514.000 points (16.065 KBbyte when zipped).

I need to publish them with other geospatial information (points ...): I've not a public GIS infrastructure with some GIS engine (GeoServer, MapServer, etc.), so I've planned to use TileMill to create tiles and then to use a little Leaflet page to publish all togheter.

At the moment I'm not able to generate tiles because TileMill is very very slow to upload the shapefile (I've started with OSM addresses that is the biggest one ....), and it's quite impossibile to export them in mbtiles. Note that the shapefile has the .shx and is shown right in QGIS. I think that I'm wrong somewhere Any suggestion? Alternatives?

I'd to use both raster tiles and vector tiles when I'll show the details.

You can see my points data at this address https://www.dropbox.com/s/a32pudxht18z832/CiviciOSM.zip

Comment: I'm using a Windows 7 pc with 4 CPU and 8 Gbyte RAM ....

Comment: I've tried both to use shapeindex command and to use spatiallite / postgis as data source. The best solution for performance is to use POSTGIS. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the standard OSM toolchain:

1. Set up a Postgis database
2. Import your filtered data using osm2pgsql
3. Create a tile style for transparent overlays
4. Generate your tiles
5. Display basemap and transparent tiles with Openlayers or leaflet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of the performance problem in TileMill. But I could offer you an alternative solution, which is using MapSurfer.NET to visualize your dataset. It's a powerful tool for cartgoraphic representation and publishing geo-data to the web or generating tiles in different formats (mbtiles, plain files, AzureBlobStorage, etc.). MapSurfer.NET includes a desktop application, which is similar to TileMill, that helps you to create your own map style and create tiles. 
More information about this framework you can find [here](http://openmapsurfer.uni-hd.de/Framework/info.html).

Answer (score 0):

16 MBytes zipped is certainly not a big file, 160 is more like it :)

To speed up processing a shape file you have to index it. Use `shapeindex <shapefile.shp>` from `mapnik-utils` package. Standard shape index (`.qix` file) cannot be read by Mapnik (the rendering engine TileMill employs), you have to use its own tool.

Comment: Thanks Ilja! I know that 16 Mbytes is not " big" data and in fact Im quite amazed about it ....:-). I don't have installed Mapnik "directly" but only TileMill: does the command shapeindex work in this case? From command line in a DOS window? Otherwise I can try to use POSTGIS or Spatialite...

Comment: TileMill uses Mapnik, so when installing TileMill, you have installed Mapnik. Search in your `Program Files` directory (if you're using Windows) for `shapeindex.exe`. If it's not there, try downloading ["Windows 32 bit Package"](http://mapnik.org/download/) and unpacking it somewhere. `shapeindex.exe` is in there.